# tkinter not working in spyder - tk._test() works

Tags: tkinter, spyder

`tkinter` is only partially working for me. The `tk._test()` works, and when the backend is `inline`, `tkinter` does not work, but if I switch it to `Tkinter` after having tried running the below code with the Graphics backend set to `inline`, a bunch of `tkinter` windows will appear. Unfortunately, that is all. If I try running `tkinter` from then out, no new popups will appear. Nothing seems to happen, it is as if it get frozen.

This is what I am trying to run

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
greeting = tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter")
greeting.pack()
```

I am running python 3.8.8. I can't figure out what version spyder is... but it isn't the latest one.

Comment: Missing `window.mainloop()`.

Comment: @acw1668 yep, that works now. Add that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
greeting = tk.Label(window, text="Hello, Tkinter")
greeting.pack()
```

You forgot to add the window when creating the Label.

Comment: It doesn't fix the issue unfortunately, I still have to start the kernel with background graphics in `inline`, run code, then switch background graphics to `tkinter`, then the box pops up, but I can't do anymore. running the code again does nothing, and I have restart kernel, switch to `inline`, run code, switch to `tkinter` window pops up, look at it, wave, cry goodbye

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `window.mainloop()`.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
greeting = tk.Label(text="Hello, Tkinter")
greeting.pack()    
window.mainloop()
```

Result output image:

[image]